# How to deal with casual imperfections of texts? — Que faire face aux imperfections occasionnelles des textes en français ?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons

I think it's clear we cannot afford one question for every piece of French text that someone doesn't understand. Nobody asked about what their brother meant in his last facebook wall post (yet).

Though every now and then, a question turns out to be about understanding some published content that looks genuine, but is actually unclear or obviously erroneous. We've seen cases of badly (or very badly) written French, or the problem might come down to a mere random typo, or sometimes it's just impossible to know what the author meant.

Knowing this, the question might not even be relevant to the OP themself any more.

These utterly specific questions cannot be generalized, and are not useful to the wide internet audience. They were closed as “too localized” before.
This close reason disappeared.
Now, those questions are neither *off-topic*, nor *too broad*, not *unclear* per se, and not necessarily *opinion-based*.

How should we deal with such questions now?

---

Il semble clair que l'on ne peut pas se permettre une question pour chaque extrait de texte que quelqu'un n'aurait pas compris. Pour l'instant personne n'a demandé d'expliquer ce que son frère a bien pu vouloir dire sur son mur facebook (du moins, pas encore).

Mais, de temps en temps, il arrive qu'une question porte sur la compréhension d'un contenu publié, a priori digne de confiance, mais qui n'est en réalité pas clair ou est manifestement erroné. On a recensé plusieurs cas de textes mal (ou très mal) écrits, parfois le problème se résume à une simple coquille, et parfois il est simplement impossible de savoir ce que l'auteur a voulu dire.

Sachant cela, il se peut que la question ne soit même plus pertinente aux yeux de l'OP lui-même.

Ces questions extrêmement spécifiques ne sont pas généralisables et ne sont d'aucun intérêt pour les internautes. Elles étaient closes avec pour motif « too localized ». Ce motif de clôture a disparu. Reste que ces questions ne sont ni *hors sujet* ni *de portée trop large*, elles ne sont pas *obscures* en soi, et ne sont pas nécessairement *trop subjectives*.

Que faire lorsqu'on se trouve face à de tels cas ?

Comment: This issue first raised in this post http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/what-does-y-replace-in-this-prose-fragment.

Comment: Why did “too localised” disappeared?

Comment: @Édouard, my take is that it was misunderstood by people asking questions, thus leading to dissent like the one in the referenced question.

Answer (score 5):

On top of not being useful, such questions are diluting the valuable content of this site. Too numerous they would make the questions list uninteresting/boring to browse.

If we think such questions are an issue, this is because we find them *off-topic* in a certain way. So is it possible to simply add a new close reason to the *off-topic* list, as *too localized* actually disappeared? I would suggest something like "The subject of this question is a (French) text that contains typos, grammatical mistakes, or that is abstruse." should this feasible.

The idea is to keep the content of the site valuable without frustrating the OP who couldn't know that the text he/she was struggling with was actually bad.

Comment: My understanding -- moderators will confirm or infirm -- is that we wanted to have as third custom close reason a replacement of "too localized" but found no good formulation (and changing formulation is apparently a pain).  BTW I'm not sure that we are really limited to three reasons, SO has five if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I am not sure either of the flexibility we have. SO has 5 primary reasons and 7 "off-topic because".

Comment: It would be interesting to review questions we previously closed as "too localized" and see how well your formulation would handle them. (Replacing my boss make me take the habit of giving work to others ;-)

Comment: Good idea. But we have to keep in mind that the scope of 'too localized' was actualy wider than the specific close reason I am suggesting here.

Comment: -1 pourquoi décider qu'un texte qui n'est pas normalisé, industriellement pensé, ne valorise pas le site? D'autant plus que la question posée était complétement 'dans les clous'

Comment: @cl-r Je ne comprends pas le lien avec l'industrie. Ce dont il est question ici, c'est de se prémunir des questions basée sur un texte erroné ou abscons alors que c'est précisément ce côté erroné ou abscons qui fait que la question est posée (exemple: "J'ai lu *J'ai manger du pain*, dans le journal. Pouvez-vous m'expliquer cet usage de l'infinitif ?"). Cela ne se limite donc pas au cas d'espèce référencé en commentaire sous la question, c'est beaucoup plus large. A la limite, si quelqu'un avait voté *close* à cette question, toi tu aurais voté *leave open*. Est-ce un problème?

Comment: @Shlublu industriel se réfère ici à l'industrie de la communication, avec ses bilans positifs et négatifs. La phrase n'est pas spontanée, mais validée par des cabinets de com', retravaillée pour un certain public, ou pour faire acheter du coca-cola. Le problème n'est pas d'écarter les questions comme celle que vous  citez,  mais de ne pas ouvrir le site à la totalité des formes de la francophonie, au kaléidoscope des usages possibles, au nom d'un nord atlantisme bien pensant, oubliant la majorité des francophones qui vivent hors de l'Europe et de l'Amérique du nord. PS. j'ai voté *reopen*

Answer (score 3):

While I think that some such questions sometimes may need to be closed, I would be very prudent when doing so. A question such as “What does this sentence means?” can be seen as too localised at first, but an answer might render the question interesting: by pointing out that the sentence has a structure which is peculiar to French or a literary style which not might be obvious even to native speakers, e.g.

---

Bien que je pense que certaines questions de ce type doivent parfois être fermés, je recommanderais la prudence avant d’agir de la sorte. Une question comme « Que signifie cette phrase » peut sembler trop restreinte à première vue, mais parfois une réponse peut encore la « sauver ». En faisant remarquer une structure particulière au français ou un style littéraire qui ne sauterait pas aux yeux, même à ceux des francophones maternels.

Comment: You can make any bad question worth to be kept by writing an answer which don't answer the question but digress on a more or less related issue.  It has at least two problems: the burden is on those answering and not on those asking and it incites to ask similar questions by the OP or others.

Comment: I don’t think @cl-r 's answer to “[What does “y” replace in this prose fragment?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/what-does-y-replace-in-this-prose-fragment)” is a digression on “a more or less related issue”. Their answer attempts to provides tools needed to understand the question, tools which are part to the “french language and its usage”. Now I agree that the question in itself is “too localised”. But I believe it can be edited to make it more on the point and useful for other prospective users.

Answer (score -2):

Je ne suis pas du tout d'accord avec l'interprétation que vous donnez à la question mise en référence.

Il s'agit d'un problème de *francophonie* où le déchiffrage grammatical pose problème d'intelligibilité.

Un étudiant hautement motivé découvre un texte de pure littérature et butte sur un problème qu'aucun traducteur automatique ne peut résoudre.

Il ne demande pas de traduction de la totalité du texte mais accroche sur un mot précis, pour lequel il propose les solutions qu'il a envisagées.

Supprimer l'élan de compréhension semble en contradiction avec le but du site, qui parle de français (dans sa globalité), et pas seulement d'orthographe et grammaire française.

**Edit**

D'autre part vouloir fermer une discussion qui a déjà obtenu réponses et commentaires positifs, n'est-il pas en contradiction avec la valorisation souhaité du site?
 S'accorder le droit divin de dire ce qui est bon au peuple et ce qu'il ne l'est pas, alors qu'il manifeste de l'intérêt pour des situtations qui sortent des sentiers battus ?

Comment: Un texte de pure littérature? La transcription d'un interview?

Comment: Le texte est littéraire, qu'il soit transcription ou pas dans le sens qu'il transcrits les émotions d'un être humain face à un fait inattendu, il ne démontre rien, ne prouve rien, ni ne décide quoique ce soit. Il fait entrer l'oralité, l'instant vécu dans la page en essayant de ne pas en trahir la force sensorielle ressentie.

Comment: Il n'y a pas de droit divin, et personne ne souhaite se l'arroger : pour qu'une question soit fermée, il faut tout d'abord qu'elle passe un vote. A supposer qu'elle le passe, si quelqu'un trouve cela regrettable, plus tard, il peut en demander la réouverture. Ce sont donc les utilisateurs qui décident. La question ici, c'est de rendre explicite ce cas particulier de fermeture, et ce n'est rien d'autre.

Comment: @Shlublu S'il en est ainsi, pourquoi pas, mais est-il normal que la question soit toujours [on hold] avec 1 reopen?

Comment: @cl-r Oui, bien sûr. Il en faut plusieurs, cela fonctionne de façon similaire aux *close*.

Comment: @cl-r, tu veux pousser le site vers un site d'explication littéraire ?  Parce que, que l'OP s'en soit rendu compte ou pas au moment où il a posé la question, c'est bien de ça dont il s'agit ici, d'interpréter un texte pas clair.  Et ce genre de chose est beaucoup trop subjective pour SE.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Pas du tout, je ne veux (ni ne peux) rien. J'essaie seulement d'entendre des questions pertinentes. Naturellement je fais référence à la question d'Indoxia (qui a donné de bons arguments pour la défense de sa question) portant sur un *y* . Dans un texte dont je ne saurais définir la complexité grammatical, je n'ai rien ré-interprété, seulement "désarticulé le poulet pour en trouver le sot-l'y-laisse", en essayant d'être le plus objectif possible. Le texte est clair en lui-même, mais n'aborde pas un sujet facile à exprimer.  Rencontrer les phrases à périodes fait partie du jeu.