# Listes des questions fermées car "too localized"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

Je fais écho [à cette discussion](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/467/how-to-deal-with-casual-imperfections-of-texts), et plus particulièrement au commentaire d'Un Francophone sous ma réponse.

Est-il possible d'extraire, ou de demander à Stack Exchange d'extraire la liste des question ayant été fermées car "too localized" ?

L'idée est de déterminer la proportion d'entre elles qui l'ont été du fait de la qualité du texte en français sur lequel elles s'appuient.

Answer (score 2):

Voici la liste des questions fermées pour le motif « too localized ». Je l'ai extraite en filtrant les résultats de [ce script](https://stackapps.com/questions/4279/list-the-closed-questions-on-a-site) pour ne garder que les questions dont le motif est `TL`.

- [How is the 'root' of the verbs referred to?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/how-is-the-root-of-the-verbs-referred-to) (TL; +2; 1 answer)
- [Meaning of “décologie administrative”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2576/meaning-of-decologie-administrative) (TL; +4)
- [« Ça ne marche pas » qu'est-ce que ça signifie ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3306/ca-ne-marche-pas-quest-ce-que-ca-signifie) (TL; +1; 1 answer)
- [« cracher dans des langues »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3308/cracher-dans-des-langues) (TL; +1; 1 answer)
- [Translation of "the Table of Contents"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4434/translation-of-the-table-of-contents) (TL; 0; 1 answer)
- [What does "Q" stand for in the context of graphing?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4533/what-does-q-stand-for-in-the-context-of-graphing) (TL; 0; 2 answers)
- [« Je vous envoie » ou « Je vous envois » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4575/je-vous-envoie-ou-je-vous-envois) (TL; +1; 1 answer)
- [Where is this accent from?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4592/where-is-this-accent-from) (TL; -1; 1 answer)
- [Que veut dire « des près » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4599/que-veut-dire-des-pres) (TL; 0; 1 answer)
- [Pourquoi « quinze jours d'attentes » avec un « s » à la fin ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5735/pourquoi-quinze-jours-dattentes-avec-un-s-a-la-fin) (TL; +3; 1 answer)
- [Le mot « empathie » n'est pas dans le dictionnaire ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5802/le-mot-empathie-nest-pas-dans-le-dictionnaire) (TL; +1; 1 answer)
- [Example of using "devoir" in passé composé?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5887/example-of-using-devoir-in-passe-compose) (TL; +2; 1 answer)
- [Can you guess what the correct phrase is?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5929/can-you-guess-what-the-correct-phrase-is) (TL; 0; 1 answer)
- [Différence entre « interprétation » et « interprétariat » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6179/difference-entre-interpretation-et-interpretariat) (TL; +2)
- [Quelle est la différence entre les verbes « fuir », « s'enfuir », « échapper » et « s'échapper » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6444/quelle-est-la-difference-entre-les-verbes-fuir-senfuir-echapper-e) (TL; +2)
- [Translation of "Pour que"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/translation-of-pour-que) (TL; -2; 1 answer)

Et voici la liste des questions fermées comme « *too localized* » puis effacées. J'ai parcouru la liste des questions effacées (à laquelle seuls les modérateurs ont accès) à la main.

- [Industrial revolution words [closed]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/61/industrial-revolution-words)
- [When looking for an apartment to rent in France what does the word “dressing” mean? [closed]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/when-looking-for-an-apartment-to-rent-in-france-what-does-the-word-dressing-me)
- [What's the definition of “mettre son grain de sel” and “en faire tout un fromage”? [closed]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/whats-the-definition-of-mettre-son-grain-de-sel-and-en-faire-tout-un-fromage)
- [Quelle est la définition de « avoir un faible pour »? [closed]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1573/quelle-est-la-definition-de-avoir-un-faible-pour)
- [The difference between “pension” and “demi-pension” [closed]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1663/the-difference-between-pension-and-demi-pension)
- [“Future Antérieur” vs. “Futur Simple” [closed]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1930/future-anterieur-vs-futur-simple)
- [Quels sont les sens/usages du mot « or » ? [closed]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2282/quels-sont-les-sens-usages-du-mot-or)
- [French time terms? [closed]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/french-time-terms)
- [translation for “bottle cap”? [closed]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2453/translation-for-bottle-cap)
- [How do you pronounce Ypres? [closed]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/how-do-you-pronounce-ypres)
- [Quel est l'infinitif pour « égarèrent » ? [closed]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2796/quel-est-linfinitif-pour-egarerent)
- [Meaning of “ouvrir le feu”? [closed]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/meaning-of-ouvrir-le-feu)
- [Cette ou Cet opportunité ? [closed]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5717/cette-ou-cet-opportunite)
- [Transcription - Avant de partir au Japon [closed]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5789/transcription-avant-de-partir-au-japon)